# How to use regex in R?

Tags: r

I want to remove the dashes and keep only the first 4 substrings except for the last character.

```
sub.maf.barcode <- gsub("^([^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*).{1}$", "\\1", ori.maf.barcode$Tumor_Sample_Barcode)

> ori.maf.barcode$Tumor_Sample_Barcode[1:5]
[1] "TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A-11D-A382-10" "TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A-11D-A382-10"
[3] "TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A-11D-A382-10" "TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A-12D-A382-10"
[5] "TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01A-21D-A382-10"
```

Expected output:

```
[1] "TCGA-2K-A9WE-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01"
[3] "TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01"
[5] "TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01"
```

Comment: If the substrings are all the same length, you could do `substr(ori.maf.barcode$Tumor_Sample_Barcode, 1, 15)`

Comment: kidney data isn;t  it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```r
gsub('.-[^-]*-[^-]*-.[^-]*$', "", ori.maf.barcode$Tumor_Sample_Barcode)
#> [1] "TCGA-2K-A9WE-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01" 
#> [4] "TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01"
```

Or

```r
substr(ori.maf.barcode$Tumor_Sample_Barcode, 1, 15)
#> [1] "TCGA-2K-A9WE-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01" 
#> [4] "TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(ori.maf.barcode$Tumor_Sample_Barcode, "^([^-]+-){3}\\d+")
```

-output

```
[1] "TCGA-2K-A9WE-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01"
[4] "TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01" "TCGA-2Z-A9J5-01"
```